# Looping Through Each Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code that will automate the sending of documents to multiple recipients. My Excel spreadsheet looks like this:

```
    Name    Report #1   Report #2   Report #3
Recipient   Email 1     Email 1     Email 1
            Email 2     Email 2     Email 2
            Email 3     Email 3     Email 3
            Email 4                 Email 4
            Email 5
```

The code uses cell B1 to find the report name and locate it on the drive. Then send it as an attachment to the recipients in column B. I have so far been able to do that much:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Email_Report()

'Purpose: AustrTomate sending of reports via email to a list of specified Recipients

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim EmailRng As Range, Recipient As Range
Dim strTo As String

Set EmailRng = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B2:B20")

    For Each Recipient In EmailRng
        strTo = strTo & ";" & Recipient.Value
    Next

    strTo = Mid(strTo, 2)
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

        With OutMail
           .strTo = strTo
           .CC = ""
           .BCC = ""
           .Subject = "Report Name Here"

           .Body = "Body text here"

           .Attachments.Add ("File location here")
           .Send
        End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing



End Sub
```

But I am having a hard time finding an elegant solution to make the code go on to column C, D, and so on to do the same thing. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your `For Each` statement with something like this. This will roll through the cells in the 2nd row so I'm guessing you'll need to add another loop to roll through all of the rows once you have this working.

Note: I switched `To` to `strTo` because `To` was giving me an error. It's a reserved keyword in VBA.

New loop to get emails:

```
For column = 2 To EmailRng.Cells.Count
    If Cells(2, column) <> "" Then 'Don't bother cell is blank
        'Don't add a semicolon with the first address
        If strTo = "" Then
            strTo = Cells(2, column)
        Else
            strTo = strTo & ";" & Cells(2, column)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks for pointing this out. I copy pasted straight from Notepad and didn't notice the To discrepancy. I fixed it now in the original post. So yes, actually that's what my problem is: I cannot seem to find an elegant solution for my code to "run horizontally" after it's done through the first column. Any ideas? Short of copy-pasting the same code every time and changing the set range?

Comment: @Starnox I believe the code I gave you should run horizontally. Do you mean run vertically? If so, how do you determine what Row to stop on? When the first column is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop the recipients, join the values using Join with ; as the delimiter like this:

```
Sub Email_Report()

'Purpose: AustrTomate sending of reports via email to a list of specified Recipients

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, EmailRng As Range, Recipient As Range, strTo As String, X As Long

Set EmailRng = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("B2:B20")
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    For X = 1 To 3 'Number of columns to poll across
        strTo = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(0, X - 1)), ";") 'Get all values in column and populate to strTo without looping
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
               .strTo = strTo
               .CC = ""
               .BCC = ""
               .Subject = "Report Name Here"
               .Body = "Body text here"
               .Attachments.Add ("File location here")
               .Send
            End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    Next
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```